# How do I create a complete new rpm including all dependencies - Ansible disconnected package

Tags: rhel, package-management, rpm, rpmbuild

I need to install Ansible on my node which doesn't have internet connection. I downloaded and installed all the dependencies. Now I would like to create a complete package which includes all the dependencies.

Main rpm - ansible-2.3.0.0-3.el7.noarch.rpm

Dependencies

- python2-pyvmomi-6.5-1.el7.noarch.rpm
- python-crypto-2.0.1-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm
- python-crypto-2.6.1-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm
- python-ecdsa-0.11-3.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
- python-httplib2-0.7.7-3.el7.noarch.rpm
- python-keyczar-0.71c-2.el7.noarch.rpm
- python-paramiko-1.15.1-1.el7.noarch.rpm
- python-pyasn1-0.1.6-2.el7.noarch.rpm
- PyYAML-3.10-11.el7.x86_64.rpm
- sshpass-1.05-5.el7.x86_64.rpm

This is the complete list in case someone might be able to help.

Is there any specific process to create a package ?

Comment: @here any help ?

Answer (score 0):

The packages are going to be installed one by one, and renaming them will probably break future updates to the system. Plus writing a monolithic package is gonna be frustrating a time consuming (alas you'd probably learn a lot)

You could just compress al the dependencies (ie. tar.gz) and then move them as a single file.

```
tar cvfz ansible-2-3-fulldeps.tar.gz *.rpm
```

After decompressing the file you can install all packages at once using a wildcard:

```
tar xvfz ansible-2-3-fulldeps.tar.gz
yum install *.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for creating a package with all of them. I've done something similar at my workplace. You can use this after you download all the rpm's needed in a folder (dependencies + actual ansible installer):

```
yum --nogpgcheck localinstall *.rpm
```

**yum** knows how to resolve dependencies alone, and you don't need to manually install them in order.

I know how annoying it is to install x.rpm and the output would be "you need to install y.rpm first" instead of "x.rpm installed succesfully".

If you want you can create a local repository for others to have this and install it in a more nice manner. Cheers!